# i want to reserve the last state of the controller

Tags: angularjs

I added a google maps api v3 and I added markers and routes to this map. When I change the view and I come back to the maps view  I don't found elemnts that I added.So I want to charge the last state of the controller without reloading it from the beging.

Answer (score 0):

If it's mandatory that, no matter to what view the user goes, the markers should be there when the user comes back, your best bet would be to set those markers on `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`.

You can inject and use `$rootScope` in any controller, although you shouldn't do it often to keep your responsabilities separated.